# Retrieve complex parameter from view Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Rails 3.1 app and I've the following big issue: I must retrieve some parameter from view to controller

This is my view:

```
 <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">

              <td><%= text_field_tag("bulk_warehouse_serial#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}", bulk_warehouse.serial, :disabled => true) %></td>
              <td><%= text_field_tag("bulk_warehouse_asset#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}", bulk_warehouse.asset, :disabled => true)%></td>




          <td><%= check_box_tag "enable_record#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}",1,false,{:onclick => "bulk_warehouse_serial#{@count}.disabled = 
                                                                            bulk_warehouse_asset#{@count}.disabled = 
                                                                            !this.checked;"}%></td>
                <td class="last">
            <%= link_to "#{t("web-app-theme.delete", :default => "Delete")}", bulk_warehouse_path(bulk_warehouse), :method => :delete, :confirm => "#{t("web-app-theme.confirm", :default => "Are you sure?")}" %>
          </td>


        </tr>
      </div>          
<%  @count = @count +1 %>
```

And in my controller I've something such as:

```
 ...
    @count = 0
    ...
```

and this what is generated by web server log:

```
"warehouse"=>{"asset"=>"turiturira", "serial"=>"caricarira", "project_id"=>"1", "hardware"=>{"brand_id"=>"21"}, "hardware_id"=>"60", "state_id"=>"4", "position_id"=>"1", "logicalwarehouse_id"=>"3", "extra_id"=>"3"}, "bulk_warehouse_serial270"=>"t", "bulk_warehouse_asset270"=>"test", "enable_record2_page0"=>"1", "bulk_warehouse_serial2"=>"uela2", "bulk_warehouse_asset2"=>"bela2", "enable_record3_page0"=>"1"}_
```

e
Now, in my controller I need an action where I must check first all "enable_record#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}" values and then doing some actions. How can I make if statement in my controller? I was thinking something such as:

```
@count=0
@page = params[:page]
@count_max = 10
until @count == @count_max

if params[:warehouse][:enable_record#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}] == 1
...doing something...
end
@count=@count+1
end
```

but it gives me an surror; any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems quite complicated for whatever it is you're trying to do, but I'll refrain from refactoring your approach.  There is one standout in your code however -- it is the dynamic construction of the key you're using.  You may want to construct it with a string then 'symbolize' it:

```
key = "enable_record#{@count}_page#{params[:page]}".to_sym
if params[:warehouse][key] == 1
...doing something...
end
```

Note: you also might reconsider the equality condition.  The hash's value may not be an integer 1 as your code suggests and could actually be "1" (a string). Ensure both values are the same type (using either .to_s or .to_i) if there's any uncertainty.